# How do you access Teradata datalab in Python

Tags: python, teradata

I can access Teradata datalab (Sandbox) in SAS.

Is it possible to access it through SAS?

Comment: Teradata offers a DBAPI driver `teradatasql` for Python which is available from PyPI. For more details see https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-sql-driver-for-python